# How do you declare a function generic on types T and U that disallows an empty intersection of T and U

Tags: typescript, generics

Given the interface:

```
interface Extendable<T> {
    extend<U>(q: U): T & U
}
```

How would you modify it so that there is a compilation error when the intersection of T and U is empty?

That is, `T & U === never`.

For my use case, types T and U are specific string values or the union thereof.

Below is an example of how the interface might be used:

```
type S = 'Select'
type U = 'Update'
type D = 'Delete'
type I = 'Insert'
type V = 'Values'
type SUDI = S | U | D | I
type SUD = S | U | D
type SV = S | V

declare let sud: SUD, s: S, i: I;
declare let root: Extendable<SUDI>
declare let where: Extendable<SUD>

root.extend(sud)
// return type (S | U | D | I) & (S | U | D) = (S | U | D)

where.extend(i)
// return type (S | U | D) & (I) = never
// can this be a compile error instead?
```

Comment: Could you include examples of what you would like to avoid? If `T` and `U` are object types `T&U` will never be `never`. Primitive intersections don't necessarily reduce to never either.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship you want to express is actually just an extends relationship. If you have a union, a subset of the union members extends the original union

```
interface Extendable<T> {
    extend<U extends T>(q: U): T & U
}

type S = 'Select'
type U = 'Update'
type D = 'Delete'
type I = 'Insert'
type SUDI = S | U | D | I
type SUD = S | U | D

declare let sud: SUD, s: S, i: I;
declare let root: Extendable<SUDI>
declare let where: Extendable<SUD>

root.extend(sud) //ok
where.extend(i) // I !extends SUD
```

**Edit**

We can use a conditional type to trigger an error if there are no common members between the two unions. Since the relation is not a traditional one the error is not going to be a traditional compiler error either. If the condition is not met we add an extra string literal type to the parameter that will trigger an error.

```
type ValidateCommonunionMemebers<T, U, TErr> = [T] extends [U] ? {} :
    [U] extends [T] ? {} : TErr;

interface Extendable<T> {
    extend<U>(q: U & ValidateCommonunionMemebers<T, U, "T and U should have some common memebers">): T & U
}

type S = 'Select'
type U = 'Update'
type D = 'Delete'
type I = 'Insert'
type V = 'Values'
type SUDI = S | U | D | I
type SUD = S | U | D
type SV = S | V

declare let sud: SUD, s: S, i: I, sudi:SUDI;
declare let root: Extendable<SUDI>
declare let where: Extendable<SUD>

root.extend(sud)
// return type (S | U | D | I) & (S | U | D) = (S | U | D)

where.extend(i) // Error Type '"Insert"' is not assignable to type '"T and U should have some common memebers"'.
where.extend(sudi)
```

Comment: Note quite. For example if `declare let root: SUDI` then `where.extend(root)` should be valid. But it's not because SUDI does not extend SUD. Also I added a new types `V` and `SV`. You should be able to extend SV with SUD, because they intersect on S.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I'm inclined to agree with basarat. The generic condition I want is <U extends (T & U extends never ? never : unknown)>. This definition has a circular reference... and I don't think there's a work around.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you modify it so that there is a compilation error when the intersection of T and U is empty? That is, `T & U === never`.

`T & U` will never be `never` unless either `T` or `U` are never.

You cannot block out `never` as a placeholder for a generic as it can be assigned to anything e.g.

```
declare const c: never; 
const x: number = c; // No Error
const y: {a : number} = c; // No Error
```

Comment: `type A = 'a' | 'b'`
`type B = 'c' | 'd'`
`type C = A & B`
type C resolves to never

Comment: A never can be assigned to anything sadly.

Comment: Because "everything can be derived from a falsum"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion